# Given $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ find $m_k \in \{k,k+1,\ldots,2k\}$ so that $\frac{m_k}{k} \to 1+\varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the following statement that is in a proof of a book I am reading:

> Given $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ find $m_k \in \{k,k+1,\ldots,2k\}$ so that $\frac{m_k}{k} \to 1+\varepsilon$.

The issue I am having is showing it in full generality for any $\varepsilon$. I can do it for numbers of the form $1/N$. For example, if $\varepsilon = 1/2$, then

- pick $m_k = 1$ if $k = 1$
- pick $m_k = (3/2)k$ if $k$ is even
- pick $m_k = (3/2)(k+1)$ if $k\geq 3$ is odd.

Then clearly $m_k/k \to 1 + \varepsilon = 3/2$.

I presume that a similar argument can be made for any number of the form $\varepsilon = p/q$ with $q > p > 0$ (however I have not shown this yet). These numbers are dense in $[0,1]$ so maybe I can somehow use that fact to show it is true for a general irrational $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$?

It is probably something simple, but who knows. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m_k = k+\lfloor k \epsilon \rfloor$.

Since $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, we have $\lfloor k \epsilon \rfloor \in \{0,...,k-1 \}$, hence $m_k \in \{k,...,2k-1 \}$.

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\lfloor k x \rfloor}{k} = x$, so it follows that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{m_k}{k} = 1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\lfloor k x \rfloor}{k} = x$ is the case since $(k-1) x \leq \lfloor k x \rfloor \leq k x$?

Comment: @Suugaku: Yes, that will work.